# How to add prefix to all jars using Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, build, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have a root Gradle project with group id of `org.name` and multiple sub-projects named `org.name.one`, `org.name.two`, `org.name.three`.

Currently .jars are generated as `one-1.0.jar`, `two-1.0.jar`, `three-1.0.jar` however I want them to be named `name-one-1.0.jar`, `name-two-1.0.jar`, `name-three-1.0.jar`.

How can I achieve it using Kotlin DSL (build.gradle.kts files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you use `shadow` plugin to package a fat jar.

If you use gradle shadow plugin, you can do something like the following to control the jar name:

```kotlin
tasks {
  withType<ShadowJar> {
    archiveBaseName.set("foo-${project.name}")
  }
}
```

In case you have sub projects, you can apply to allprojects/subprojects:

```kotlin
allprojects {
  tasks {
    withType<ShadowJar> {
      archiveBaseName.set("foo-${project.name}")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You should also wrap everything in subprojects { } to apply this to all sub-projects.